# Aix command help in Echo

Tags: shell

QQ can some one help

```
[db2image@nzakuap047wbcx2{p1tudb047}]:/opt/db2/db2image > db2 -ec list tablespaces | grep -x 0 | wc -l
       1

a=`db2 -ec list tablespaces | grep -x 0 | wc -l`
[db2image@nzakuap047wbcx2{p1tudb047}]:/opt/db2/db2image > echo $a
0
```

Why is that i am not getting 1 for echo $a ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get result `1` because that is the result of `db2 -ec list tablespaces | grep -x 0 | wc -l` which will be assigned to `a` variable.

You need to create an alias if you want to reuse the command.

```
alias a=`db2 -ec list tablespaces | grep -x 0 | wc -l`
```